# Cannot access a key value pair of a changed object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Please excuse my code

From an external source , I am given the following [external data which I name loxAP3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtgb6.png)

to which I am trying to firstly retrieve svg data related to the rooms.image property and then change the incoming svg data to work with react, using the following code.

```js
createRoomData(loxAPP3, socket) {
  console.log(loxAPP3)
  let rooms = []
  let rawRooms = loxAPP3.rooms
  for (const rawRoom in rawRooms) {
    rooms.push(rawRooms[rawRoom])
  }
  //add svg property with blank property value
  rooms.forEach((room) => {
    room.svg = ''
  })
  //fetch image data for each room in loxApp3.rooms
  rooms.forEach((room) => {
    const image = room.image
    socket
      .send(image)
      .then(function(respons) {
          //console.log("Successfully fetched svg image " + respons );   // success
          room.svg = respons
          //console.log(room.svg) // success console returns room.svg data
        },
        function(err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      );
  })
  this.setState({
    rooms: rooms
  }, () => {
    console.log(rooms) // success rooms[0].svg is shown as having been populated
    this.adjustSvGImageToReact()
  })
}
```

[console.log(rooms)  // success rooms[0].svg is shown as having been populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rct7W.png)

However the problem comes when I try and manipulate the room object, if I log a property that already existed from the original data, there is no problem, however if  I try an fetch the .svg property it comes back not as undefined but as the empty string I first set it to be.

```
adjustSvGImageToReact() {  
  this.state.rooms.forEach((room)=>{
    console.log(room.name) // success
    console.log(room.uuid) // success
    console.log(room.svg) //empty

  }) 
}
```

Comment: `socket.send()` is asynchronous so `room.svg = respons` will happen ***after*** you setState and after you call `this.adjustSvGImageToReact()`

Comment: Also important to understand that objects logged in console are not snapshots, they are live objects. Properties that are updated after you log the object will show as updated in console

Comment: I suspected as much, but being new to javascript  and callbacks, I have no real idea how to ensure I have the full dataset before proceeding. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of the `socket.send()` promises instead of calling them inside `forEach`

Then you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to set the state and call `adjustSvGImageToReact()` after the socket requests have completed

```
const svgPromises = rooms.map((room) => {
  const image = room.image
  return socket
    .send(image)
    .then((respons)=> room.svg = respons)

})

Promise.all(svgPromises).then(() => {
  this.setState({rooms: rooms}, () => {
    console.log(rooms) // success rooms[0].svg is shown as having been populated
    this.adjustSvGImageToReact()
  });
}).catch(err=>console.log('One of the socket requests failed'))
```

Comment: Thank you i will do that